# rabbitmqctl shows nodedown, but not if I use Invoke-Command and supply computer name

Tags: powershell, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have RabbitMQ 3.6.5 / Erlang 18.0 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I know that my RabbitMQ node "rabbit@447523-testap01" is up because I can connect to it with the management UI.  If I run the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat status
```

I get the following "nodedown" message:

```
Status of node 'rabbit@447523-testap01' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@447523-testap01': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@447523-testap01']

rabbit@447523-testap01:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on 447523-testap01
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
  * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
  * suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-33@447523-testap01'
- home dir: C:\Users\myusername
- cookie hash: 4Y+9yh7QrOGXO8aIm4YQZw==
```

**However**, if I use PowerShell Invoke-Command executed on the same machine and supply the computer name as in the following, it reports that it's up!

```
invoke-command -computername 447523-testap01 -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat' status}
```

If I omit the -computername parameter though, it reports the same "nodedown" message.  What is going on here?  I've verified that the Erlang cookie file is the same between C:\Windows\.erlang.cookie and %UserProfile%\.erlang.cookie, and the RabbitMQ log files don't show any errors.

Comment: are you running the commands from 447523-testap01 or a management workstation?

Comment: I'm running the commands from 447523-testap01.